# Exporting a conda environment with local pip installs

Tags: python, windows, pip, development-environment, conda

I have exported my currently active environment with

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

This is very convenient since it keeps track of both conda and pip installed packages. However, I have a few packages (shapely and basemap for example) installed locally by pip from a .whl file from Christoph Gohlke's compiled packages for Windows. When I try to recreate my environment by

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

pip returns with an error since it cannot find these packages in its index (obviously). Is there a way to tell pip in the conda export step where to look for these local packages? The .whl files can be assumed to be in the same directory as the environment.yml file.

Comment: `shapely` and `basemap` both have conda packages available in conda's community channel conda-forge. It might be easier for you to just install conda packages instead.

Comment: I didn't know that - that is quite convenient for these packages. Unfortunately my corporate firewall doesn't like conda-forge :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no way to actually get it to create entries for the `.whl` file automatically from what I'm aware of.

The simplest way to get this to work is by manually altering the `environment.yml` file and adding the `.whl` file in the list under `- pip:`. I tried this by downloading the `.whl` package for `nose` and placing it in the same directory as my `env.yml` file, the structure looked like this:

```
name: python3_test
dependencies:
- openssl=1.0.2h=1
- pip=8.1.2=py35_0
- python=3.5.1=5
- readline=6.2=2
- setuptools=23.0.0=py35_0
- sqlite=3.13.0=0
- tk=8.5.18=0
- wheel=0.29.0=py35_0
- xz=5.2.2=0
- zlib=1.2.8=3
- pip:
   - nose-1.3.7-py3-none-any.whl
```

If it is located in a different directory, just supply the directory. The path, of course, should be valid when issuing `conda create env`.

The `pip` command issued when running `conda env create -n <name> -f <file.yml>` is a [pretty straightforward install](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/conda-env/conda_env/installers/pip.py) so the semantics of installing with pip from the command line should be similar. Heck, you could even add the `url` for the `.whl` file in the `requirements.yml` and the installation would still go down smoothly. Again, keeping the rest the same and using the url for downloading `nose`:

```
- pip:
   - https://pypi.python.org/packages/15/d8/dd071918c040f50fa1cf80da16423af51ff8ce4a0f2399b7bf8de45ac3d9/nose-1.3.7-py3-none-any.whl#md5=3135984cc9cfcbe5d9c46e166d6743b0
```

Using any url shouldn't cause any issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a specific example of an environment.yml that uses a URL to link to wheel files from Christoph Gohlke's compiled packages for Windows:

```
# run: conda env create --file environment.yml
name: test-env
dependencies:
- python>=3.5
- anaconda
- pip
- pip:
  - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/bofhrmxk/opencv_python-3.1.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35245610/1493069