# Can not find installed packages in virtual environment. ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: anaconda, python-3.6

My environment

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

$ python --version
Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

I created a virtual environment and using it; Set environment variables;

```
$ sudo chown -R tonynb:tonynb anaconda3     # anaconda3 owns to me

$ which python
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python

$ conda create --name ve        # My virtual environment

$ source activate ve

(ve)$ which python
/opt/anaconda3/envs/ve/bin/python
```

I started to install packages

```
(ve)$ pip install pymongo

(ve)$ pip install jupyter notebook

(ve)$ jupyter notebook

(ve)$ pip freeze
pymongo==3.5.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.1.0
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
....
```

Everything is fine. But when I am in jupyter notebook, error happened when I type this

```
import pymongo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'
```

It seems that it only search packages inside

`/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages` not `/opt/anaconda3/envs/ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

```
$ which pip
/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip 

(ve)$ which pip
/opt/anaconda3/envs/ve/bin/pip
```

Did I misunderstand something? Or anything goes wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `which pip`? You did not install any packages into the environment when you created it, so I'm very surprised that Python is available from that environment. Moreover, you should use conda to install packages whenever possible, since pip and conda don't interact with eachother

Comment: @darthbith `/opt/anaconda3/envs/ve/bin/pip`.  I edit last part of my code. Do you mean I shouldn't use `pip install <packages>` in my virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, you should use `conda install`

Comment: Thanks @darthbith. It works. But it seems I can not use `conda install -r requirement` like pip.

Comment: That's correct. You have to use an environment file. See https://gist.github.com/luiscape/19d2d73a8c7b59411a2fb73a697f5ed4 and https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/conda/PiM9sjWyXFU and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245401/combining-conda-environment-yml-with-pip-requirements-txt

Comment: What is your `conda list --export > requirements.txt` output?