# Can't recreate Conda environment in docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, miniconda

I created a conda environment from a fresh installation of miniconda3.

After that I exported it and this is the content of the file (my only extra install was flask):

```
name: myenv
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - ca-certificates=2018.03.07=0
  - certifi=2018.11.29=py37_0
  - click=7.0=py37_0
  - flask=1.0.2=py37_1
  - itsdangerous=1.1.0=py37_0
  - jinja2=2.10=py37_0
  - libcxx=4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - libcxxabi=4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - libedit=3.1.20170329=hb402a30_2
  - libffi=3.2.1=h475c297_4
  - markupsafe=1.1.0=py37h1de35cc_0
  - ncurses=6.1=h0a44026_1
  - openssl=1.1.1a=h1de35cc_0
  - pip=18.1=py37_0
  - python=3.7.1=haf84260_7
  - readline=7.0=h1de35cc_5
  - setuptools=40.6.2=py37_0
  - sqlite=3.26.0=ha441bb4_0
  - tk=8.6.8=ha441bb4_0
  - werkzeug=0.14.1=py37_0
  - wheel=0.32.3=py37_0
  - xz=5.2.4=h1de35cc_4
  - zlib=1.2.11=h1de35cc_3
prefix: /Users/rossid/miniconda3/envs/phadmin
```

now what I want, is to recreate this environment in a docket image so I created this Dockefile

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
ADD * myappdir/
RUN conda env create -f /myappdir/environment.yml
```

but it will fail with:

```
Step 1/5 : FROM continuumio/miniconda3
 ---> d3c252f8727b
Step 2/5 : ADD * myappdir/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2afbf5ea75bd
Step 3/5 : RUN conda env create -f /myappdir/environment.yml
 ---> Running in 7f916bd46979
Solving environment: ...working... failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - tk==8.6.8=ha441bb4_0
  - ncurses==6.1=h0a44026_1
  - markupsafe==1.1.0=py37h1de35cc_0
  - readline==7.0=h1de35cc_5
  - zlib==1.2.11=h1de35cc_3
  - openssl==1.1.1a=h1de35cc_0
  - xz==5.2.4=h1de35cc_4
  - libcxxabi==4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - libcxx==4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - libffi==3.2.1=h475c297_4
  - sqlite==3.26.0=ha441bb4_0
  - python==3.7.1=haf84260_7
  - libedit==3.1.20170329=hb402a30_2
```

why is this happening? If I try to do the same to create another environment it works. If I remove the build version, some dependencies are resolved (I mean the third coordinate in dependencies).

I tried to add more channels like conda-forge, but nothing.

Also my .condarc file is empty.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: perhaps [this may help](https://github.com/datitran/object_detector_app/issues/41), as I have faced a similar issue in the past. You could remove build version and version version although some apps may work differently if a different version is installed

Comment: Is it the same OS to generate the environment.yml and within the Docker image?

Comment: some of these libraries are platform dependent like: libcxxabi and libcxx these are for OSX, but in Linux they are not available. Some of these libs only work if I put them in the PIP section. I'd like to make an environment.yml that is cross platform but I don't know how...

Comment: @gotch4 I don't think cross-platform-compatible conda environment files exist at the moment, and that's because conda itself isn't fully cross-platform-compatible. Correct me if I'm wrong, internet.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and I find multiple ways to solve it. The main problem with your approach is conda is not platform independent, so will force the environments to use pip.

**1. Conda Like Solution**

Change your *my_env.yml* so that all the dependencies apart from pip goes under the pip dependency. Notice that the syntax is different when you move under the pip.

For instance:

```
name: myenv
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
   - pip=18.1
   - pip:
     - wheel==0.32.3
```

Then go to your Dockerfile and add the following line:

```
RUN conda env update -n base --file myenv.yml
```

**2. Good old Pip way**

Export your conda environment into a pip requirements file as [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57845418/1305058)

```
conda install pip
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then go to your Docker file and add the following line:

```
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: god why does package management suck so much in python?

Answer (score 0):

The docker build fails because your input yml file includes platform-specific build constraints. For example:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - tk==8.6.8=ha441bb4_0
  - ncurses==6.1=h0a44026_1
  - markupsafe==1.1.0=py37h1de35cc_0
  - readline==7.0=h1de35cc_5
  - zlib==1.2.11=h1de35cc_3
  - openssl==1.1.1a=h1de35cc_0
  - xz==5.2.4=h1de35cc_4
  - libcxxabi==4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - libcxx==4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - libffi==3.2.1=h475c297_4
  - sqlite==3.26.0=ha441bb4_0
  - python==3.7.1=haf84260_7
  - libedit==3.1.20170329=hb402a30_2
```

Those packages contain platform specific hashs (e.g. `ha441bb4_0`). Basically, you are trying to install packages from the OS platform on a linux platform. That's why berkay's answer would work for most of the use case. A simpler way to solve this problem is add `from-history` argument while exporting your conda environment.

`conda env export -f env_explicit.yml --from-history`

This argument will just includes packages, which you explicitly specified during installation. This argument will also ignore any platform-specific dependencies.

And your new Dockerfile will looks like following:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
ADD * myappdir/
RUN conda env create -f /myappdir/env_explicit.yml
```

Reference: [conda fails to create environment from yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554431/conda-fails-to-create-environment-from-yml/55576493#55576493)