# conda fails to create environment from yml

Tags: python, conda, ubuntu-server

I’m trying to run the code below to create a virtual Python environment from a YAML file.  I’m running the code in the command line on Ubuntu server.  The virtual environment is named py36.  When I run the code below, I get the message below.  The environment also doesn’t get created.  Is this problem caused because I have several packages that I had to install using pip instead of Anaconda?  Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

I created the YAML file following the example from:

```
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24093/how-to-clone-python-working-environment-on-another-machine
```

### Code:

```
conda env create -f py36.yml
```

### py36.yml

```
name: py36
channels:
  - anaconda
  - cvxgrp
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - beautifulsoup4=4.6.3=py36_0
  - patsy=0.5.1=py36_0
  - sqlite=3.25.3=ha441bb4_0
  - tk=8.6.8=ha441bb4_0
  - asn1crypto=0.24.0=py36_1003
  - ca-certificates=2018.11.29=ha4d7672_0
  - certifi=2018.11.29=py36_1000
  - cffi=1.11.5=py36h5e8e0c9_1
  - clangdev=4.0.0=default_0
  - cryptography=2.3.1=py36hdbc3d79_1000
  - cryptography-vectors=2.3.1=py36_1000
  - cycler=0.10.0=py_1
  - fftw=3.3.8=h470a237_0
  - freetype=2.9.1=h6debe1e_4
  - glpk=4.65=h16a7912_1
  - gmp=6.1.2=hfc679d8_0
  - icu=58.2=h0a44026_1000
  - idna=2.8=py36_1000
  - kiwisolver=1.0.1=py36h2d50403_2
  - lapack=3.6.1=1
  - libiconv=1.15=h1de35cc_1004
  - libpng=1.6.35=ha92aebf_2
  - libxml2=2.9.8=hf14e9c8_1005
  - lightgbm=2.2.1=py36hfc679d8_0
  - llvmdev=4.0.0=default_0
  - matplotlib=2.2.3=py36h0e0179f_0
  - metis=5.1.0=3
  - mkl_fft=1.0.6=py36_0
  - mkl_random=1.0.1=py36_0
  - mlxtend=0.13.0=py_1
  - openblas=0.2.20=8
  - openmp=4.0.0=1
  - openssl=1.0.2p=h1de35cc_1002
  - pandas=0.23.4=py36hf8a1672_0
  - pycparser=2.19=py_0
  - pyopenssl=18.0.0=py36_1000
  - pyparsing=2.2.0=py_1
  - pysocks=1.6.8=py36_1002
  - python=3.6.6=h4a56312_1003
  - pytz=2018.5=py_0
  - selenium=3.141.0=py36h470a237_0
  - tbb=2018_20171205=0
  - urllib3=1.24.1=py36_1000
  - cvxcanon=0.1.1=py36_0
  - cvxpy=1.0.6=py36_0
  - ecos=2.0.5=py36hf9b3073_0
  - multiprocess=0.70.4=py36_0
  - scs=1.2.6=py36_0
  - appnope=0.1.0=py36hf537a9a_0
  - backcall=0.1.0=py36_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - cvxopt=1.2.0=py36hb579ef3_0
  - decorator=4.3.0=py36_0
  - dill=0.2.8.2=py36_0
  - dsdp=5.8=hb579ef3_0
  - fastcache=1.0.2=py36h1de35cc_2
  - gsl=2.4=h1de35cc_4
  - intel-openmp=2019.0=117
  - ipykernel=4.8.2=py36_0
  - ipython=6.4.0=py36_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py36h241746c_0
  - jedi=0.12.0=py36_1
  - jupyter_client=5.2.3=py36_0
  - jupyter_core=4.4.0=py36h79cf704_0
  - libcxx=4.0.1=h579ed51_0
  - libcxxabi=4.0.1=hebd6815_0
  - libedit=3.1.20170329=hb402a30_2
  - libffi=3.2.1=h475c297_4
  - libgcc=4.8.5=hdbeacc1_10
  - libgfortran=3.0.1=h93005f0_2
  - libopenblas=0.3.3=hdc02c5d_2
  - libsodium=1.0.16=h3efe00b_0
  - mkl=2018.0.3=1
  - ncurses=6.1=h0a44026_0
  - numpy=1.15.4=py36h6a91979_0
  - numpy-base=1.15.4=py36h8a80b8c_0
  - parso=0.2.1=py36_0
  - pexpect=4.6.0=py36_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.4=py36hf512f8e_0
  - pip=10.0.1=py36_0
  - prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py36haeda067_0
  - ptyprocess=0.5.2=py36he6521c3_0
  - pygments=2.2.0=py36h240cd3f_0
  - python-dateutil=2.7.3=py36_0
  - pyzmq=17.0.0=py36h1de35cc_1
  - readline=7.0=hc1231fa_4
  - scikit-learn=0.20.1=py36h4f467ca_0
  - scipy=1.1.0=py36h28f7352_1
  - setuptools=39.2.0=py36_0
  - simplegeneric=0.8.1=py36_2
  - six=1.11.0=py36h0e22d5e_1
  - suitesparse=5.2.0=he235d88_0
  - toolz=0.9.0=py36_0
  - tornado=5.0.2=py36_0
  - traitlets=4.3.2=py36h65bd3ce_0
  - wcwidth=0.1.7=py36h8c6ec74_0
  - wheel=0.31.1=py36_0
  - xz=5.2.4=h1de35cc_4
  - zeromq=4.2.5=h378b8a2_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=hf3cbc9b_2
  - pip:
    - absl-py==0.2.2
    - astor==0.6.2
    - bleach==1.5.0
    - cython==0.28.3
    - gast==0.2.0
    - grpcio==1.12.1
    - h5py==2.8.0
    - html5lib==0.9999999
    - keras==2.2.0
    - keras-applications==1.0.2
    - keras-preprocessing==1.0.1
    - markdown==2.6.11
    - pillow==5.1.0
    - protobuf==3.5.2.post1
    - pyramid-arima==0.6.5
    - pyyaml==3.12
    - sklearn==0.0
    - statsmodels==0.9.0
    - tensorboard==1.8.0
    - tensorflow==1.8.0
    - termcolor==1.1.0
    - tqdm==4.23.4
    - werkzeug==0.14.1
    - xlrd==1.1.0
prefix: /Users/username/anaconda2/envs/py36
```

### Command line

```
conda env create -f py36.yml
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - libgfortran==3.0.1=h93005f0_2
  - pyzmq==17.0.0=py36h1de35cc_1
  - python==3.6.6=h4a56312_1003
  - prompt_toolkit==1.0.15=py36haeda067_0
  - libiconv==1.15=h1de35cc_1004
  - sqlite==3.25.3=ha441bb4_0
  - six==1.11.0=py36h0e22d5e_1
  - cryptography==2.3.1=py36hdbc3d79_1000
  - openssl==1.0.2p=h1de35cc_1002
  - libxml2==2.9.8=hf14e9c8_1005
  - libcxxabi==4.0.1=hebd6815_0
  - matplotlib==2.2.3=py36h0e0179f_0
  - ptyprocess==0.5.2=py36he6521c3_0
  - readline==7.0=hc1231fa_4
  - libedit==3.1.20170329=hb402a30_2
  - libgcc==4.8.5=hdbeacc1_10
  - xz==5.2.4=h1de35cc_4
  - pickleshare==0.7.4=py36hf512f8e_0
  - appnope==0.1.0=py36hf537a9a_0
  - scipy==1.1.0=py36h28f7352_1
  - cvxopt==1.2.0=py36hb579ef3_0
  - jupyter_core==4.4.0=py36h79cf704_0
  - dsdp==5.8=hb579ef3_0
  - ncurses==6.1=h0a44026_0
  - tk==8.6.8=ha441bb4_0
  - ecos==2.0.5=py36hf9b3073_0
  - wcwidth==0.1.7=py36h8c6ec74_0
  - scikit-learn==0.20.1=py36h4f467ca_0
  - libopenblas==0.3.3=hdc02c5d_2
  - traitlets==4.3.2=py36h65bd3ce_0
  - libsodium==1.0.16=h3efe00b_0
  - ipython_genutils==0.2.0=py36h241746c_0
  - fastcache==1.0.2=py36h1de35cc_2
  - numpy==1.15.4=py36h6a91979_0
  - numpy-base==1.15.4=py36h8a80b8c_0
  - zlib==1.2.11=hf3cbc9b_2
  - libffi==3.2.1=h475c297_4
  - pygments==2.2.0=py36h240cd3f_0
  - icu==58.2=h0a44026_1000
  - gsl==2.4=h1de35cc_4
  - libcxx==4.0.1=h579ed51_0
  - suitesparse==5.2.0=he235d88_0
  - zeromq==4.2.5=h378b8a2_0
```

Comment: I know this is quite old, but is there any reason why you must use pip for some of these packages, like tensorflow and sklearn?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

No, PyPI is not the issue. Instead, **it fails because the YAML includes platform-specific build constraints, but you are transferring across platforms**.  Specifically, examining the build numbers on the failed packages (e.g., `six=py36h0e22d5e_1`), I can see that they correspond to packages from the `osx-64` platform, but you are trying to install on a `linux-64` platform, hence the build constraints are unresolvable.

### Omit Build Info

The simplest solution to this is to omit the build info from the environment definition export.

```
conda env export -n py36 -f py36.yml --no-builds
```

There can still be issues if some of the packages are not available on `linux-64` through Conda. If this is the case, you may need to find other channels (or check PyPI), switch versions, or remove the dependency altogether. Most of the packages look standard though.

Not so important, but you can safely remove `cvxgrp` from your channels. That channel only serves an outdated version of `cvxopt` and only for `osx-64`.

### Explicit Specifications Only

Another, even more loosely defined option, is to output only what Conda refers to as *explicit specifications*. These indicate only those requirements that have been explicitly requested by the user. This includes packages, but also captures any version constraints, etc., that were provided by the user at some point.

```
conda env export -n py36 -f py36.yml --from-history
```

The advantage here is that any platform-specific dependencies will be ignored.

Comment: Hi merv, I've also had this issue and I did what you say. This created my environment in anaconda3/envs however the executables are not there and I only have the conda-meta folder without any executables to which I can add my interpreter. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @deblue please ask a new question

Comment: this answer is a godsend

Comment: the first option has entries like 'zlib=1.2.11' and includes all pypi packages

Comment: the second option has entries like 'zlib' , but ignores all pypi packages

Comment: @TejasShetty yes, since Conda cannot track when you use `pip install`, there's no way to consider a PyPI package an explicit spec. I would just merge the two: append the `pip:` section from the former to the latter.

Comment: @merv, thanks a ton. Your answer helped me get a deeper insight into handling anaconda environments especially using :pip: installed packages. 
Cheers...!

Answer (score 23):

Indeed environments keep platform build specifics under the conda-installed (*i.e.*, `dependencies`) section.
From OP's sample:

```
  - zlib=1.2.11=hf3cbc9b_2
```

, `hf3cbc9b_2` is a platform-specific version tag. You have to remove that.

If you do switch between platforms very often (OSX <-> Linux, for example), please read the answer from [@merv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55576493/687896), that is the right thing to do in your future `env export`.

For the time being, like me, just want to have it fixed, you may do it manually or run a `sed` over it:

```
sed 's/\(.*[[:alnum:]]\)=[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:].-_]*/\1/' environment.yml > env.yml
```

. That will handle the platform-specific tag without touching the `pip` section of the file.

Then you can try again with `env.yml`:

```
conda env create -f env.yml
```

> Notice that platform-specific *packages* may occur. If after removing the version tags, Conda still complains, you'll have to manually clean the packages accordingly. For example, I'm bringing an `environment.yml` from Linux to Mac, where the packages `libgcc-ng=9.1.0`, `libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0`, `libgfortran-ng=7.3.0` are not defined; I removed them by hand.

Once such cleaning was done, my `conda env create -f env.yml` worked like a charm.

Comment: this answer is a godsend

Comment: i totally agree this answer is godsend, the saviour of all humanity