# Conda 'Package conflicts for' errors?

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, dependencies, miniconda

Win 10, Python 2.7, Miniconda 4.8.3

```
conda env create -f environment.yml

Package setuptools conflicts for:
pip=19.0.3 -> setuptools ...
Package openssl conflicts for:
pyparsing=2.2.0 -> python -> openssl[version=' ...
Package thrift conflicts for:
impyla=0.14.0 -> thrift
thrift=0.9.3
...(many more)
```

How to interpret these messages ? What does **->** mean ?
How to fix this issue ? I tried some methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58216917/create-conda-environment-found-conflicts-when-solving-environment-and-findi), but no luck.

My 'channels' in environment.yml:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - conda-forge/label/broken
  - defaults
```

Comment: Wild guess: packages from the label `broken` might be actually broken.

Comment: @KlausD. - I only added that broken stuff on the suggestion of that linked question above

Comment: can you share environment.yml? If it is a yml file for a python 2x env, chances are that it contains quite old package versions as dependencies for which you might need the `free` channel