# How to fix `ResolvePackageNotFound` error when creating Conda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

When I run the following command: 
`conda env create -f virtual_platform_mac.yml`

I get this error

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - pytables==3.4.2=np113py35_0
  - h5py==2.7.0=np113py35_0
  - anaconda==custom=py35_0
```

**How can I solve this?**

I am working on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 20):

[Conda v4.7 dropped a branch of the Anaconda Cloud repository called the **free** channel](https://www.anaconda.com/why-we-removed-the-free-channel-in-conda-4-7/) for the sake of improving solving performance. Unfortunately, this includes many older packages that never got ported to the repository branches that were retained. The requirements failing here are affected by this.

## Restore `free` Channel Searching

Conda provides a means to restore access to this part of the repository through the `restore_free_channel` configuration option. You can verify that this is the issue by seeing that

```
conda search pytables=3.4.2[build=np113py35_0]
```

fails, whereas

```
CONDA_RESTORE_FREE_CHANNEL=1 conda search pytables=3.4.2[build=np113py35_0]
```

successfully finds the package, and similarly for the others.

#### Option 1: Permanent Setting

If you expect to frequently need older packages, then you can globally set the option and then proceed with installing:

```
conda config --set restore_free_channel true
conda env create -f virtual_platform_mac.yml
```

#### Option 2: Temporary Setting

As with all Conda configuration options, you can also use the corresponding environment variable to temporarily restore access just for the command:

**Unix/Linux**

```
CONDA_RESTORE_FREE_CHANNEL=1 conda env create -f virtual_platform_mac.yml
```

**Windows**

```
SET CONDA_RESTORE_FREE_CHANNEL=1
conda env create -f virtual_platform_mac.yaml
```

(Yes, I realize the cognitive dissonance of a `..._mac.yaml`, but Windows users need help too.)

**Including Channel Manually**

One can also manually include the channel as one to be searched:

```
conda search -c free pytables=3.4.2[build=np113py35_0]
```

Note that any of these approaches will only use the **free** channel in this particular search and any future searches or changes to the env will not search the channel.

#### Pro-Tip: Env-specific Settings

If you have a particular env that you always want to have access to the **free** channel but you don't want to set this option globally, you can instead set the configuration option only for the environment.

```
conda activate my_env
conda config --env --set restore_free_channel true
```

A similar effect can be accomplished by setting and unsetting the `CONDA_RESTORE_FREE_CHANNEL` variable in scripts placed in the `etc/conda/activate.d` and `etc/conda/deactivate.d` folders, respectively.  See [the documentation for an example](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables).

Comment: I'm getting the same error even after changing the settings permanently

Comment: @kamaltanwar so you did Option 1? Is it definitely a **free** channel package issue? When you check `conda info` is the **free** channel listed?

Answer (score 4):

Another solution might be explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55576493/12445701). Basically, if you import an `environment.yml` file to a different OS (e.g., from macOS to Windows) you will get build errors.

The solution is to set the flag `--no-builds` when using `export`. This does not guarantee that the `environment.yml` will actually be compatible. Some libraries, e.g. `libgfortran`, are not found on Windows channels for Anaconda (see [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7311)).

Answer (score -2):

I would use

```
CONDA_RESTORE_FREE_CHANNEL=1 conda env create -f
```

to keep using outdated/older packages