# when i'm using commdand "conda env create -f environment.yml" i'm getting this output below text

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - statsmodels==0.8.0=np113py36_0
  - jpeg==9b=vc14_0
  - numpy==1.13.1=py36_0
  - pandas-datareader==0.4.0=py36_0
  - pyqt==5.6.0=py36_2
  - libpng==1.6.27=vc14_0
  - mkl==2017.0.3=0
  - icu==57.1=vc14_0
  - requests-file==1.4.1=py36_0
  - pytz==2017.2=py36_0
  - matplotlib==2.0.2=np113py36_0
  - pip==9.0.1=py36_1
  - requests-ftp==0.3.1=py36_0
  - patsy==0.4.1=py36_0
  - qt==5.6.2=vc14_6
  - python==3.6.2=0
  - cycler==0.10.0=py36_0
  - openssl==1.0.2l=vc14_0
  - sip==4.18=py36_0
  - setuptools==27.2.0=py36_1
  - wheel==0.29.0=py36_0
  - requests==2.14.2=py36_0
  - scipy==0.19.1=np113py36_0
  - zlib==1.2.8=vc14_3
  - tk==8.5.18=vc14_0
  - vs2015_runtime==14.0.25420=0
  - python-dateutil==2.6.1=py36_0
  - six==1.10.0=py36_0
  - pyparsing==2.1.4=py36_0
  - pandas==0.20.3=py36_0
```

Comment: I updated conda, python and all packages but still getting this error...

Comment: You need to enable the free channel. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58220935/570918).