# Unable to install packages in Anaconda virtual environment. 'Packages are not available from current channels'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to create a new Python environment in Anaconda. I am using Anaconda Powershell Prompt and created the environment using the

```
conda create --name adwp1 python=3.5 -y;
conda activate adwp1  
conda install notebook=4.2.3 -y;
```

and

`pip install notebook=4.2.3`

I get the following error when I use *conda install*

```
    Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
    Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
    Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
    Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - notebook=4.2.3

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

**and when I use ** *`pip install`* then I get the following error

> ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'notebook=4.2.3'  Hint: = is not a valid
>   operator. Did you mean == ?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `=` with `==` in the `pip` command?

Comment: It works when I use the pip install with ```==```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That version of the package is not available in the official repositories, so you have to install it from somewhere else.
Luckily, this is available in the `conda-forge` user-maintained repositories.
If you trust the maintainer of the package, you can simply do:

```
conda install -c conda-forge -y notebook=4.2.3
```

## EDIT

As per @merv comment, it may also be possible to get this package by [restoring the **free** channel searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219956/how-to-fix-resolvepackagenotfound-error-when-creating-conda-environment/58220935#58220935), which can be done essentially by setting to `1` the `CONDA_RESTORE_FREE_CHANNEL` environment variable:

```
CONDA_RESTORE_FREE_CHANNEL=1 conda install -y notebook=4.2.3
```

or by setting the corresponding config flag to `true`:

```
conda config --set restore_free_channel true
```

---

As far as the `pip` command is concerned, this is simply a typo (as suggested in the error message): replacing `=` with `==` should do the trick:

```
pip install notebook==4.2.3
```

Comment: "*That version of the package is not available in the official repositories*" - technically it is, but Conda 4.7+ no longer looks in that part of the repository (designated the **free** channel). You can reenable it [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58220935/570918).

Comment: @merv thanks for pointing this out! I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I use the following code

`pip install notebook==4.2.3`

Thanks norok2

Comment: see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58651043/5218354) for a `conda`-based method