# PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages pykg-config are not available from current channels:

Tags: python, anaconda, pdftotext

I'm trying to install some new packages `pykg-config` to get access to functions necessary for a university assignment. When I try to install, I get the following:

```
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pykg-config

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/auto/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/auto/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I am trying to install pdftotext `pip install pdftotext` but I am getting errors that are stating that I need to install first this package `pykg-config`. Now when I try to install the package `pykg-config` I received the above errors again kindly help.

Comment: If you are using conda, you probobly want to use `conda install ...` instead of `pip`

Comment: Still getting errors , `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pdftotext

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch`

Comment: force using conda-forge channel `conda install -c conda-forge pykg-config`

Comment: even with that, I am still getting the same errors

Comment: `[...] but I am getting errors that are stating that I need to install first this package pykg-config` - would be helpful if you could add the error message you are getting there.

Comment: What I would try is: `conda install -c conda-forge poppler pkg-config` followed by `pip install pdftotext`. I would recommend doing this in a new environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I've faced the same issue earlier today and I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58650834/unable-to-install-packages-in-anaconda-virtual-environment-packages-are-not-av)