# Is it possible to clone environments with yaml files between conda and miniconda?

Tags: python, yaml, jupyter, conda

Does it make a difference if the yaml files are created in full anconda and then are used to setup up environments in a miniconda installation on another machine?

I tried to do this, but I am getting the.

Solving environment: failed
ResolvePackageNotFound:

I know how to clone envs like this
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24093/how-to-clone-python-working-environment-on-another-machine

Cloning like this has worked before for me.
The conda/miniconda difference might not be the cause of the error, but I am curious.

I have tried some solutions like
checking if cond-forge is installed (it is)

I also tried this:
[How to fix `ResolvePackageNotFound` error when creating Conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219956/how-to-fix-resolvepackagenotfound-error-when-creating-conda-environment)

The free channel solution does not work?
Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: The only thing that matters with regards to conda environments is `conda`. `conda` comes with *both* the miniconda distribution and the full anaconda distribution. Basically, miniconda is Python + conda. Anaconda is python + conda + >1000 packages related to scientific computing / data science. So possibly the precise `conda` version might matter.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga please write that as an answer