# How to build Conda env on Mac using Windows yml file?

Tags: virtualenv, conda

I'm creating Conda create environment from yml I generated on Windows' Miniconda install. I need to create same environment on OS X. Following the advise [found here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55576493/343215) I used the `--no-builds` option.

Also, the names of some packages under section `ResolvePackageNotFound` are clearly (many if not all) specific to Windows:

```
  - m2w64-gmp=6.1.0
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0
  - m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0
  - vc=14.1
  - vs2015_runtime=15.5.2
  - msys2-conda-epoch=20160418
  - menuinst=1.4.14
  - icc_rt=2019.0.0
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757
  - pywinpty=0.5.5
  - wincertstore=0.2
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0
  - winpty=0.4.3
```

I removed all of these from the yml file. Even then it's stalled at the following screen:

```
(base) MacBook-Air:Anaconda.d xtian$ conda env create -f 32b-qb-2019-10-05.yml 
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abor| 
Examining openssl:  10%|█████████▍                                                                                 | 29/279 [00:00<00:00, 3729.87it- ]
Comparing specs that have this dependency:  16%|██████████▉                                                          | 16/101 [05:53<31:19, 22.11s/it]
Finding shortest conflict path for openssl[version='>=1.0.2p,<1.0.3a']:  38%|███████████████▊                          | 6/16 [02:39<06:23, 38.32s/it]
```

This process is progressing at an astonishingly slow pace, and hasn't got past `openssl ... 29/279`. **Should I wait and trust Conda can figure this all out?**

Or,

Do I need another strategy--
I'm wondering if I can't remove the offending packages, each in turn, and create a series of yml files to install in order using, `$ conda env update --prefix ./env --file environment.yml  --prune`, because whatever finally works here I know I'm going to need to use it on another machine so I can share the project env with a colleague.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I would try making a YAML using `conda env export --from-history` and then delete everything in the first YAML (with `--no-builds`) that isn't in this. This is obviously less stringent in ensuring that dependencies use similar versions, but this would at least match all the packages you explicitly requested.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Try deleting the packages that your system is getting stuck on from the .yml file. i.e., remove "openssl" from .yml file.

I have been running into the same issue trying to install a .yml file created in a Windows system to a Mac system. I basically followed the same procedure you did:

-Created yml file using the --no-builds option.

-Attempted to create environment on Mac system and had several windows specific packages left under ResolvePackageNotFound section (listed below)

- m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757
- pyreadline=2.1
- pywinpty=0.5.5
- m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0
- vc=14
- m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0
- m2w64-gmp=6.1.0
- wincertstore=0.2
- icc_rt=2019.0.0
- m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0
- vs2015_runtime=14.15.26706
- winpty=0.4.3
- msys2-conda-epoch=20160418

-Deleted those from the yml file

-Attempted to create environment from updated yml file and received the following conflicts:
   - Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.

My system also got stuck trying to solve the "openssl" conflict along with a "_tflow_select". I ended up deleting those and was able to create my environment and run the code without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but thought I'd put the solution I used here...

The below outputs a yml, of --from-hist but with versions.

Create 2 yml files:

conda env export --from-hist --no-build > fromHist.yml

conda env export --no-build > full.yml

The using the shell (I used zsh), run:

IFS=$'\n'; rm crossPlatform.yml; for full in $(cat full.yml); do for hist in $(cat fromHist.yml); do echo $full | sed -n -e "s#(${hist}.*)#\1#p" >> crossPlatform.yml; done; done

This is not perfect (e.g. jupyterlab caused all dependancies beginning with this string to be included in the output yml), but much easier than trying to remove all incompatible.