# Why can't I install these specific requirements?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to create a conda environment, but it has many dependencies that anaconda seems unable to locate, always sending the same error message below:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done

    Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source. Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment: failed
    
    PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
    
  - opencv==3.4.2=py37h6fd60c2_1
  - libopencv==3.4.2=h7c891bd_1
  - pixman==0.38.0=h1de35cc_0
  - gettext==0.19.8.1=h15daf44_3
  - pyyaml==5.2=py37h1de35cc_0
  - libcxxabi==4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - mss==3.0.1=pypi_0
  - cffi==1.13.2=py37h33e799b_0
  - libprotobuf==3.11.2=hd9629dc_0
  - graphite2==1.3.13=h2098e52_0
  - pyscreenshot==0.6=pypi_0
  - scipy==1.3.1=py37h1a1e112_0
  - tensorflow-base==1.15.0=mkl_py37h032239d_0
  - jasper==2.0.14=h636a363_1
  - tornado==6.0.3=py37h1de35cc_0
  - bzip2==1.0.8=h1de35cc_0
  - c-ares==1.15.0=h1de35cc_1001
  - numpy==1.17.4=py37hfd23ef0_0
  - pycosat==0.6.3=py37h0b31af3_1002
  - cairo==1.14.12=hc4e6be7_4
  - zstd==1.3.7=h5bba6e5_0
  - grpcio==1.16.1=py37h044775b_1
  - pango==1.42.4=h060686c_0
  - protobuf==3.11.2=py37h0a44026_0
  - libvpx==1.7.0=h378b8a2_0
  - graphviz==2.40.1=hefbbd9a_2
  - tk==8.6.8=ha441bb4_0
  - libpng==1.6.37=ha441bb4_0
  - yaml==0.1.7=hc338f04_2
  - sqlite==3.30.1=ha441bb4_0
  - libcxx==4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - harfbuzz==1.8.8=hb8d4a28_0
  - pillow==6.2.1=py37hb68e598_0
  - libiconv==1.15=hdd342a3_7
  - pyobjc-core==5.2=py37_0
  - easyprocess==0.2.8=pypi_0
  - readline==7.0=h1de35cc_5
  - xz==5.2.4=h1de35cc_4
  - pcre==8.43=h0a44026_0
  - glib==2.63.1=hd977a24_0
  - libffi==3.2.1=h475c297_4
  - ffmpeg==4.0=h01ea3c9_0
  - libopenblas==0.3.6=hdc02c5d_2
  - freetype==2.9.1=hb4e5f40_0
  - openssl==1.1.1d=h1de35cc_3
  - pyobjc-framework-cocoa==5.2=py37_0
  - fontconfig==2.13.0=h5d5b041_1
  - tensorflow==1.15.0=mkl_py37hb249377_0
  - python-chess==0.30.0=pypi_0
  - kiwisolver==1.1.0=py37h0a44026_0
  - python==3.7.5=h359304d_0
  - expat==2.2.6=h0a44026_0
  - jpeg==9b=he5867d9_2
  - libgfortran==3.0.1=h93005f0_2
  - icu==58.2=h4b95b61_1
  - hdf5==1.10.2=hfa1e0ec_1
  - ruamel_yaml==0.15.87=py37h1de35cc_0
  - zlib==1.2.11=h1de35cc_3
  - libopus==1.3=h1de35cc_0
  - libtiff==4.1.0=hcb84e12_0
  - cryptography==2.8=py37hafa8578_1
  - libxml2==2.9.9=hf6e021a_1
  - libedit==3.1.20181209=hb402a30_0
  - h5py==2.8.0=py37h878fce3_3
  - wrapt==1.11.2=py37h1de35cc_0
  - pyobjc-framework-quartz==5.2=py37_0
  - pyscreen==0.3=pypi_0
  - fribidi==1.0.5=h1de35cc_0
  - ncurses==6.1=h0a44026_1
  - matplotlib==3.1.1=py37h54f8f79_0
  - numpy-base==1.17.4=py37ha711998_0
  - py-opencv==3.4.2=py37h7c891bd_1
  - nomkl==3.0=0
  - conda-package-handling==1.6.0=py37h0b31af3_1

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/r/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/r/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
```

Which I find weird because after appending all the main channels and still getting this error, I found that they are indeed avaible, for example py-opencv-3.4.2-py37h7c891bd_1 can be found here: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/py-opencv/files?version=3.4.2.

EDIT: just realized this project can only be built on a mac. Some of the dependencies aren't compartible with Windows so I guess RIP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conda fails to create environment from yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554431/conda-fails-to-create-environment-from-yml)

Comment: Are you creating the environment from an environment.yml file? If so, those dependencies are likely way over-specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`py-opencv-3.4.2-py37h7c891bd_1` is `osx-64` based build and you're trying to install into Windows OS. It's good to find the same build for Windows from the [link](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/py-opencv/files?version=3.4.2) you shared. Otherwise, just use the version without a build number. e.g. `env.yml` for you.

```
name: env-name
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - py-opencv==3.4.2
```

Comment: I just realized some of the dependencies do not exist for Windows, like:
  - pyobjc-core
  - pyobjc-framework-cocoa
  - libcxxabi
  - pyscreenshot
  - libopus
  - libvpx
  - readline
  - ncurses
  - python-chess
  - libgfortran
  - pyobjc-framework-quartz
  - pyscreen
  - libedit

Was I doomed from the start, or can I still build this somehow?

Comment: You can always use Docker or a macOS VM