# How do i create env from .yml file in conda in windows?

Tags: python, yaml, conda, miniconda, virtual-environment

I have just started using miniconda on windows and was creating an environment through a .yml file but got this error.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda env create -f crispr-env.yml

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "F:\miniana\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "F:\miniana\lib\site-packages\conda_env\cli\main.py", line 80, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "F:\miniana\lib\site-packages\conda_env\cli\main_create.py", line 79, in execute
        spec = specs.detect(name=name, filename=expand(args.file),
      File "F:\miniana\lib\site-packages\conda_env\specs\__init__.py", line 40, in detect
        if spec.can_handle():
      File "F:\miniana\lib\site-packages\conda_env\specs\yaml_file.py", line 18, in can_handle
        self._environment = env.from_file(self.filename)
      File "F:\miniana\lib\site-packages\conda_env\env.py", line 151, in from_file
        return from_yaml(yamlstr, filename=filename)
      File "F:\miniana\lib\site-packages\conda_env\env.py", line 137, in from_yaml
        data = validate_keys(data, kwargs)
      File "F:\miniana\lib\site-packages\conda_env\env.py", line 36, in validate_keys
        for key in data.keys():
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
    environment variables:
                     CIO_TEST=<not set>
      CONDA_AUTO_UPDATE_CONDA=false
                    CONDA_EXE=F:\miniana\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
                   CONDA_EXES="F:\miniana\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
                   CONDA_ROOT=F:\miniana
                     HOMEPATH=\Users\Aakash Yadav
                         PATH=F:\miniana;F:\miniana\Library\mingw-w64\bin;F:\miniana\Library\usr\bin
                              ;F:\miniana\Library\bin;F:\miniana\Scripts;F:\miniana\bin;C:\Program
                              Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java
                              \javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program
                              Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\Sys
                              tem32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program
                              Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;c:\Program Files\Common
                              Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
                              Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
                              Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
                              Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
                              Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows
                              Performance Toolkit\;C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin;C:\Program
                              Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin;C:\Users\Aakash
                              Yadav\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Googl
                              e\Chrome\Application;F:\miniana\condabin;F:\miniana\pkgs;F:\miniana;F:
                              \miniana\Library\bin;F:\miniana\Scripts;F:\pilercr1.06
                 PSMODULEPATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
                   RASMOLPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\RasWin
           REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
        VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
    active environment : None
           user config file : C:\Users\Aakash Yadav\.condarc
     populated config files : C:\Users\Aakash Yadav\.condarc
              conda version : 4.8.3
        conda-build version : not installed
             python version : 3.8.3.final.0
           virtual packages :
           base environment : F:\miniana  (writable)
               channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
              package cache : F:\miniana\pkgs
                              C:\Users\Aakash Yadav\.conda\pkgs
                              C:\Users\Aakash Yadav\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
           envs directories : F:\miniana\envs
                              C:\Users\Aakash Yadav\.conda\envs
                              C:\Users\Aakash Yadav\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                   platform : win-64
                 user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.14393
              administrator : True
                 netrc file : None
               offline mode : False
    
    
    An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

crispr-env.yml:

```
name: crispr-env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults

dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - blas=1.0=openblas
  - ca-certificates=2020.4.5.1=hecc5488_0
  - certifi=2020.4.5.1=py37hc8dfbb8_0
  - hmmer=3.2.1=he1b5a44_2
  - joblib=0.14.1=py_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.33.1=h53a641e_7
  - libedit=3.1.20181209=hc058e9b_0
  - libffi=3.2.1=hd88cf55_4
  - libgcc-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libgfortran-ng=7.3.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libopenblas=0.3.6=h5a2b251_2
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - ncurses=6.2=he6710b0_0
  - nomkl=3.0=0
  - numpy=1.17.4=py37hd5be1e1_0
  - numpy-base=1.17.4=py37h2f8d375_0
  - openssl=1.1.1f=h516909a_0
  - pandas=0.25.3=py37he6710b0_0
  - pip=20.0.2=py37_1
  - prodigal=2.6.3=h516909a_2
  - python=3.7.6=h0371630_2
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
  - python_abi=3.7=1_cp37m
  - pytz=2019.3=py_0
  - readline=7.0=h7b6447c_5
  - scikit-learn=0.22.1=py37h22eb022_0
  - scipy=1.3.2=py37he2b7bc3_0
  - setuptools=46.1.3=py37_0
  - six=1.14.0=py37_0
  - sqlite=3.31.1=h7b6447c_0
  - tk=8.6.8=hbc83047_0
  - wheel=0.34.2=py37_0
  - xz=5.2.4=h14c3975_4
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
```

i changed the dir. and the command and i am getting this error:

```
C:\Windows\System32\CRISPRcasIdentifier>conda env create -f crispr-env.yml -n crispr-env
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - zlib==1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - libgfortran-ng==7.3.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libopenblas==0.3.6=h5a2b251_2
  - tk==8.6.8=hbc83047_0
  - openssl==1.1.1f=h516909a_0
  - scikit-learn==0.22.1=py37h22eb022_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64==2.33.1=h53a641e_7
  - readline==7.0=h7b6447c_5
  - xz==5.2.4=h14c3975_4
  - numpy==1.17.4=py37hd5be1e1_0
  - sqlite==3.31.1=h7b6447c_0
  - numpy-base==1.17.4=py37h2f8d375_0
  - prodigal==2.6.3=h516909a_2
  - libstdcxx-ng==9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - pandas==0.25.3=py37he6710b0_0
  - scipy==1.3.2=py37he2b7bc3_0
  - nomkl==3.0=0
  - libgcc-ng==9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - hmmer==3.2.1=he1b5a44_2
  - libedit==3.1.20181209=hc058e9b_0
  - python==3.7.6=h0371630_2
  - ncurses==6.2=he6710b0_0
  - libffi==3.2.1=hd88cf55_4
```

Should i delete these dependencies or is there another way to solve this package error?

Comment: Show us the YAML file!

Comment: Looking at the environment file, do you really need those dependencies to be that specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues. First, going across platforms (**linux-64** to **win-64**) is not directly supported. [There are other answers that address this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55576493/570918). Second, and more prohibitive, is that [Bioconda does not support Windows](https://bioconda.github.io/user/versions.html#operating-systems) and some of the packages (e.g., `hmmer`) are specifically from there.

Alternatives could be either building up the dependencies in Conda env, plus a compiler meta-package (`compiler-cxx`, `make`), then installing non-Windows software from source (e.g., [see HMMER documentation](http://hmmer.org/documentation.html)); or running Conda under WSL.

Comment: THANKS very much for the help! It worked in ubuntu.