# ResolvePackageNotFound,can't add these package

Tags: conda

ResolvePackageNotFound:

- ld_impl_linux-64=2.33.1
- intel-openmp==2020.2=254
- libxcb=1.14
- libgcc-ng=9.1.0
- libgfortran-ng=7.3.0
- mkl==2020.2=256
- libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0

configure:mac os,pycharm

I have no clue about how to solve it.I try download tar.bz2 package,and conda install --use-local xxx,but it does't work.

could anyone help?
Is this a operation system problem?

Comment: *"is this [an OS] problem?"* Yes, these have indications of being **linux-64** platform, and not all Conda packages have equivalents across platforms. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55576493/570918. Please provide more than just the error message if you want further help.

Comment: @ merv thanks for your advice.I removed some linux-based packagess.And I installed some packages separately.I used brew xxx command,that helps.Finally,I can run my code.But I actually have no clue about those linux packages for.