# I cannot create a conda env in a Docker container although I can create the env in my computer

Tags: docker

I want to create a Docker container with a Python app ([Spliceai](https://github.com/Illumina/SpliceAI)) that requires many libraries.  This app works on my computer so I have created an yml file to create the container. This is the code

```
# Define base image
FROM continuumio/anaconda3

# Set working directory for the project
WORKDIR /app

# Create Conda environment from the YAML file
COPY environment_lookup3.6.yml  .
RUN conda env create -f environment_lookup3.6.yml 

# Override default shell and use bash
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "env", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

# Activate Conda environment and check if it is working properly
RUN echo "Making sure flask is installed correctly..."
RUN python -c "import pandas"

# Python program to run in the container
# COPY run.py .
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "env", "spliceai"]
```

This returns the following error

```
[+] Building 143.8s (8/10)                                                                                                                                                        
=> [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                            0.0s
=> => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                              0.0s
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                         0.1s
=> => transferring dockerfile: 634B                                                                                                                                         0.0s
=> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/continuumio/miniconda3:latest                                                                                                     1.6s
=> [1/6] FROM docker.io/continuumio/miniconda3@sha256:f3637fcc44fac7c20aebcc6fb8910cf76139ff2f4e6a7777d7643460bee50922                                                      0.0s
=> [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                            0.0s
=> => transferring context: 2.04kB                                                                                                                                          0.0s
=> CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                0.0s
=> [3/6] COPY environment_lookup3.6.yml  .                                                                                                                                  0.0s
=> ERROR [4/6] RUN conda env create -f environment_lookup3.6.yml                                                                                                          142.1s
------                                                                                                                                                                            
> [4/6] RUN conda env create -f environment_lookup3.6.yml:                                                                                                                       
#0 1.230 Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done                                                                                                          
#0 135.1 Solving environment: ...working... failed                                                                                                                                
#0 135.1                                                                                                                                                                          
#0 135.1 ResolvePackageNotFound:                                                                                                                                                  
#0 135.1   - readline==8.2=hca72f7f_0
#0 135.1   - setuptools==58.0.4=py36hecd8cb5_0
#0 135.1   - ncurses==6.4=hcec6c5f_0
#0 135.1   - libffi==3.3=hb1e8313_2
#0 135.1   - pip==21.2.2=py36hecd8cb5_0
#0 135.1   - libcxx==14.0.6=h9765a3e_0
#0 135.1   - openssl==1.1.1t=hfd90126_0
#0 135.1   - tk==8.6.12=h5d9f67b_0
#0 135.1   - python==3.6.13=h88f2d9e_0
#0 135.1   - zlib==1.2.13=h4dc903c_0
#0 135.1   - xz==5.4.2=h6c40b1e_0
#0 135.1   - ca-certificates==2023.5.7=h8857fd0_0
#0 135.1   - sqlite==3.41.2=h6c40b1e_0
#0 135.1 
------
Dockerfile:9
--------------------
  7 |     # Create Conda environment from the YAML file
  8 |     COPY environment_lookup3.6.yml  .
  9 | >>> RUN conda env create -f environment_lookup3.6.yml 
 10 |      
 11 |     # Override default shell and use bash
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c conda env create -f environment_lookup3.6.yml" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

To debug this, I have created a new env using the yml file and this work ok.

This is my first day working with Docker and I am still a bit confused although I have been reading and trying this all day. I wonder if a possible reason for this error may be due to my Anaconda being installed on an external drive so when running  `/bin/sh`  it cannot be found ??

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to [conda fails to create environment from yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554431/conda-fails-to-create-environment-from-yml)

I just checked the first package from the error

readline==8.2=hca72f7f_0

the format here is package=version=build

the above package is meant for osx https://anaconda.org/anaconda/readline/files

I understand that you are trying to make a conda yaml file in macosx and try to create same env in docker container which is running on a linux based image.

You can try to do the following things and see whichever works for you:

- When creating the yaml file add this flag --no-builds
- If the above option does not work for you create yaml file from a similar platform (linux in this case)