# pip freeze creates some weird path instead of the package version

Tags: python, path, pip, requirements.txt

I am working on developing a python package. I use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to add the required package into the requirement.txt file. However, I realized that some of the packages, instead of the package version, have some path in front of them.

```
numpy==1.19.0
packaging==20.4
pandas @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/38d1301c-8fa9-4d2f-662e-34dddf33b183/volume/pandas_1592841668171/work
pandocfilters==1.4.2
```

Whereas, inside the environment, I get:

```
>>> pandas.__version__
'1.0.5'
```

Do you have any idea how to address this problem?

Comment: Not sure why this is happening, but it looks like pip freeze is outputting a [direct reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#id62) for some reason. There is a discussion on Github about this issue: [pip freeze does not show version for in-place installs](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8174)

Comment: Does "pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt" provide the expected results?

Comment: Yes. "pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt" resolved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help you, if I did, consider upvoting / accepting my answer ;)

Comment: Done. I recently joined stackoverflow. Upvoting is not active yet :).

Answer (score 337, accepted):

It looks like this is an open issue with `pip freeze` in version `20.1`, the current workaround is to use:

```
pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```

In a nutshell, this is caused by changing the behavior of `pip freeze` to include [direct references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references) for distributions installed from direct URL references.

You can read more about the issue on GitHub:

[pip freeze does not show version for in-place installs](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8174)

[Output of "pip freeze" and "pip list --format=freeze" differ for packages installed via Direct URLs](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8176)

[Better freeze of distributions installed from direct URL references](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/7612)

Comment: 2 years after your post and this is still relevant, thank you

Comment: 3 years after your post and this is still relevant, thank you

Comment: The slight issue is that the output is different between the commands; `pip freeze` excludes `pip` and `setuptools` from frozen list but `pip list --format=freeze` includes them.