# What are the @ symbols in pip freeze?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I typically work in conda on a Mac, but I find myself needing to use pip on Linux. I verified pip was in my conda env, and then created a `requirements.txt` file:

```
conda activate my_env
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

The output in the requirements file looks like this:

```
appnope @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/4f734db2-9ca8-4d8b-5b29-6ca15b4b4772/volume/appnope_1606859466979/work
arcgis==1.9.0
argon2-cffi @ file:///opt/conda/conda-bld/argon2-cffi_1645000214183/work
argon2-cffi-bindings @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c6f9b05d-dc80-4dbc-7473-70bfcb66883c/volume/argon2-cffi-bindings_1644569703264/work
async-generator==1.10
...
```

What do these @ symbols signify, and will this create issues when setting up pip envs on different operating systems?

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62886215/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62885911/pip-freeze-creates-some-weird-path-instead-of-the-package-version