# pip install force cache

Tags: python, git, pip

I am currently building a testing/linting pipeline for a certain python project. It is split up into a build process that has access to our private repositories through ssh. At this step I export the project dependencies to a `requirements.txt` file,

```
poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt --without-hashes
```

(I have also tried to use pip freeze)

Then I create a folder called `wheelhouse` and create wheels for each dependency of this project,

```
pip3 wheel --wheel-dir=wheelhouse -r requirements.txt
```

The next step of this pipeline is not supposed to have access to our private repositories through ssh, therefore I want this step to **only** use the `wheelhouse` cache to install the dependencies.

When I attempt this method, the requirement.txt folder will look something in the lines of:

```
package_on_PyPi==x.y.z
private_package @ git+ssh://git@......
```

and when I use the command

```
pip3 install --only-binary=:all: --no-index --find-links=wheelhouse -r requirements.txt
```

pip still attempts to clone the git repository where `private_package` resides.

My question is: Is there a way to force pip to only attempt to install `private_package` from the wheelhouse, and fail otherwise?

Comment: Instead of `pip freeze` try [`pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62886215/7976758) and inspect `requirements.txt`. If it still contains URLs instead of package names — edit it to remove URLs, only leave package names.