requirements.txt containig system dependency
I am trying to make requirements.txt using pip freeze > requirements.txt,
but it contains a system dependency.
I have also tried a virtual environment, but it is still taking some system files that contain in that venv.
This is what I am getting:
asgiref @ file:///Users/cbousseau/work/recipes/ci_py311/asgiref_1677957028708/work
Django @ file:///Users/cbousseau/work/recipes/ci_py311/django_1677970851911/work
djangorestframework==3.15.0
mysqlclient==2.2.4
python-dotenv==1.0.1
sqlparse @ file:///private/var/folders/k1/30mswbxs7r1g6zwn8y4fyt500000gp/T/abs_16ptvrhamb/croot/sqlparse_1690901943673/work

This is what I am expecting:
asgiref==3.8.0
Django==4.2
djangorestframework==3.15.0
setuptools==68.2.2
sqlparse==0.4.4
wheel==0.41.2

Note: I have also tried Virtual Environment and base.
Update : pipreqs Working Fine but still I am curios to know why default pip freeze > requirements.txt giving system dependency.

you could try using pipreqs

What happens when if call pip with the specific python version? python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt

python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt  also giving same result

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62886215/7976758 Try pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+freeze+weird

Probably the reason for that behavior is that you are using pip cli utility directly, instead consider launching it with (do not forget to activate your venv first tho):
python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt

