# My requirments.txt file doesn't have list of all library I have used in project

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, requirements.txt

I have create a new conda env. Then after complete the project, I have generated pickle file. Now when I am trying to generated requirements.txt it is not giving me list of all library or packages

```
(carprediction) F:\Car Dekho Dataset>pip3 freeze > requirements.txt

(carprediction) F:\Car Dekho Dataset>pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

I have tried both the command still it's not working

Output in file is as follow

```
certifi==2020.12.5
wincertstore==0.2
```

Am I doing something wrong ?
Blockquote

wincertstore==0.2

Comment: You can refer to this answer: [From conda create requirements.txt for pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777849/from-conda-create-requirements-txt-for-pip3)

Comment: I read the answer and tried command written there but still few libraries are missing like numpy, pandas , sklearn

Answer (score 0):

Check your installed packages using

```
pip freeze
```

see if all the packages are showing properly

On the other hand you can try this:

```
conda list --export > requirements.txt
```

Works nearly similarly to `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
There's quite some difference between conda and pip. You can read about it [here](http://have%20you%20tried%20%22conda%20list%20--export%20%3E%20requirements.txt%22%20?%20%20There%27s%20quite%20some%20difference%20between%20conda%20and%20pip.%20You%20can)

You can read more about pip and conda in this [article](https://coderefinery.github.io/reproducible-research/03-dependencies/)

**Update 1:**
the conda command to install numpy is

```
conda install -c anaconda numpy
```

activate your conda environment and install numpy and finally run `pip freeze` to check packages or `conda list --export > requirements.txt` to list all the packages in requirements.txt

Comment: I have run pip freeze and actually I am surprised why numpy, pandas, sklearn is not in this env. It is in my system, I guess it is not in this env, which I have created for this project. Could you please help me with that ?

Comment: Since you're using conda it might be a good idea to use conda commands to install packages. Atleast that's how I would do it. The conda install package command for numpy is "conda install -c anaconda numpy".
Don't forget to activate virtual end first. I'm updating the previous answer with the command