# Creating environment manually on Cloud GPU without conda

Tags: python, pip, virtual-environment

I have access to university Cloud GPU which does not have conda installed (and I am not allowed to install it). I am trying to install [ChartOCR](https://github.com/soap117/DeepRule) which comes with a `txt` file for creating the environment using

```
conda create  --name DeepRule --file DeepRule.txt
```

How do I manually install / replicate the environment on the Cloud GPU without conda? The CloudGPU allows me to use virtual environment using

```
python3 -m venv --system-site-packages ~/myvenv
```

This is what I tried:

```
python3 -m venv --system-site-packages ~/ChartOCR-env
source ~/ChartOCR-env/bin/activate
git clone https://github.com/soap117/DeepRule
cd DeepRule
pip install -r DeepRule.txt

ERROR: Invalid requirement: '@EXPLICIT' (from line 4 of DeepRule.txt)
```

Comment: you can install conda in your home directory. There is no need for admin rights

Comment: Apart from that - yml files for creating conda envs and pips requirement format are different and package names might be different. You will need to look at `DeepRule.txt` and convert it to a `requirements.txt` file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From conda create requirements.txt for pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777849/from-conda-create-requirements-txt-for-pip3)