# Creating Heroku App from Streamlit with environment.yml rather than requirements.txt

Tags: python, heroku, anaconda, streamlit, requirements.txt

According to several online articles like [this](https://gilberttanner.com/blog/deploying-your-streamlit-dashboard-with-heroku/) one, you need to create a `requirements.txt` file to deploy a streamlit app via Heroku. My project has an `environment.yml` file for a conda environment instead, and I'm wondering if it's possible to use that rather than `requirements.txt`? Thanks!

Comment: There're buildpacks to create conda environment at Heroku dynos. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55090663/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+conda

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47949173/7976758