# Packages not found in the current channels Conda

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

I was given a .yml file to set up an environment but I keep running into this issue. I've read on here to add conda-forge to the channels, and it was already added. I tried rearranging the channels since I read that it reads the channels in order. I tried updating conda as well. I'm not sure if this is relevant but my version of conda is 24.1.2 and python is 3.10.13.

```
Channels:
 - plotly
 - bioconda
 - anaconda
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: osx-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - zstd==1.5.0=ha4553b6_1
  - zlib==1.2.11=h166bdaf_1014
  - zeromq==4.3.4=h2531618_0
  - yarl==1.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0
  - yaml==0.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - xz==5.2.5=h7f8727e_1
  - xorg-xproto==7.0.31=h27cfd23_1007
  - xorg-xextproto==7.3.0=h0b41bf4_1003
  - xorg-renderproto==0.11.1=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-libxt==1.3.0=hd590300_0
  - xorg-libxrender==0.9.10=h7f98852_1003
  - xorg-libxext==1.3.4=h0b41bf4_2
  - xorg-libxdmcp==1.1.3=h7f98852_0
  - xorg-libxau==1.0.9=h7f98852_0
  - xorg-libx11==1.8.4=h0b41bf4_0
  - xorg-libsm==1.2.3=hd9c2040_1000
  - xorg-libice==1.0.10=h7f98852_0
  - xorg-kbproto==1.0.7=h7f98852_1002
  - wrapt==1.12.1=py39he8ac12f_1
  - widgetsnbextension==3.5.1=py39h06a4308_0
  - wheel==0.41.2=py39h06a4308_0
  - websocket-client==0.58.0=py39h06a4308_4
  - webencodings==0.5.1=py39h06a4308_1
  - umap-learn==0.5.3=py39h06a4308_0
  - tornado==6.1=py39h27cfd23_0
  - tktable==2.10=h14c3975_0
  - tk==8.6.11=h1ccaba5_0
  - terminado==0.12.1=py39hf3d152e_1
  - termcolor==1.1.0=py39h06a4308_1
  - tensorflow-base==2.6.0=py39h23a8cbf_0
  - tensorflow==2.6.0=py39hf3d152e_0
  - tensorboard-data-server==0.6.0=py39hca6d32c_0
  - tbb==2021.5.0=hd09550d_0
  - tapi==1100.0.11=h039ab34_1
  - suitesparse==5.10.1=h9e50725_1
  - stdlib-list==0.8.0=py39h06a4308_0
  - statsmodels==0.13.0=py39hce5d2b2_1
  - sqlite==3.36.0=hc218d9a_0
  - soupsieve==2.5=py39h06a4308_0
  - sniffio==1.2.0=py39h06a4308_1
  - snappy==1.1.8=he6710b0_0
  - sleef==3.5.1=h9b69904_2
  - six==1.15.0=py39h06a4308_0
  - sigtool==0.1.3=h695e95d_0
  - sed==4.8=h7b6447c_0
  - scipy==1.7.1=py39hee8e79c_0
  - scikit-learn==1.0.2=py39h51133e4_1
  - readline==8.1=h27cfd23_0
  - re2==2021.08.01=h9c3ff4c_0
  - r-survival==3.5_5=r41h133d619_0
  - r-spatial==7.3_16=r41h133d619_0
  - r-rpart==4.1.19=r41h06615bd_0
  - r-nnet==7.3_19=r41h57805ef_0
  - r-nlme==3.1_159=r41h8da6f51_1
  - r-mgcv==1.8_40=r41h5f7b363_1
  - r-matrix==1.5_4.1=r41h316c678_0
  - r-mass==7.3_58.3=r41h133d619_0
  - r-lattice==0.21_8=r41h133d619_0
  - r-kernsmooth==2.23_20=r41hd009a43_1
  - r-foreign==0.8_84=r41h133d619_0
  - r-cluster==2.1.3=r41h8da6f51_1
  - r-class==7.3_22=r41h57805ef_0
  - r-base==4.1.1=hb93adac_1
  - qt==5.12.9=hda022c4_4
  - pyzmq==22.3.0=py39h295c915_2
  - pyyaml==5.4.1=py39h5eee18b_3
  - pytorch==1.8.0=cpu_py39h0fbb4fb_1
  - python-igraph==0.9.9=py39hfef886c_0
  - python-annoy==1.17.2=py39h3d6467e_1
  - python==3.9.7=hb7a2778_3_cpython
  - pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0
  - pyrsistent==0.17.3=py39h27cfd23_0
  - pyqtwebengine==5.12.1=py39h0fcd23e_8
  - pyqtchart==5.12=py39h0fcd23e_8
  - pyqt5-sip==4.19.18=py39he80948d_8
  - pyqt-impl==5.12.3=py39hde8b62d_8
  - pyqt==5.12.3=py39hf3d152e_8
  - pynndescent==0.5.10=py39h06a4308_0
  - pyjwt==2.1.0=py39h06a4308_0
  - pthread-stubs==0.4=h36c2ea0_1001
  - protobuf==3.15.8=py39he80948d_0
  - pixman==0.42.2=h59595ed_0
  - pillow==8.3.2=py39ha612740_0
  - pcre2==10.37=he7ceb23_1
  - pcre==8.45=h295c915_0
  - patsy==0.5.2=py39h06a4308_1
  - pango==1.48.10=h54213e6_2
  - pandoc==2.14.2=h7f98852_0
  - pandas==1.3.3=py39h8c16a72_0
  - openssl==1.1.1w=h7f8727e_0
  - openjpeg==2.4.0=h3ad879b_0
  - numexpr==2.7.3=py39hde0f152_1
  - numba==0.55.1=py39h51133e4_0
  - nss==3.69=hb5efdd6_1
  - nspr==4.30=h9c3ff4c_0
  - notebook-shim==0.2.3=py39h06a4308_0
  - ninja-base==1.10.2=hd09550d_5
  - ninja==1.10.2=h06a4308_5
  - networkx==3.1=py39h06a4308_0
  - ncurses==6.2=he6710b0_1
  - nbclassic==0.5.5=py39h06a4308_0
  - mysql-libs==8.0.25=hfa10184_3
  - mysql-common==8.0.25=ha770c72_3
  - multidict==5.2.0=py39h5eee18b_3
  - mpfr==4.1.0=h9202a9a_1
  - mpc==1.3.1=hfe3b2da_0
  - mkl==2020.4=h726a3e6_304
  - mistune==0.8.4=py39h27cfd23_1000
  - metis==5.1.0=hf484d3e_4
  - matplotlib-base==3.4.3=py39hbbc1b5f_0
  - matplotlib==3.4.3=py39h06a4308_0
  - markupsafe==2.0.1=py39h27cfd23_0
  - markdown==3.3.4=py39h06a4308_0
  - make==4.3=hd18ef5c_1
  - lz4-c==1.9.3=h295c915_1
  - llvmlite==0.38.1=py39h7d9a04d_0
  - llvm-tools==14.0.4=he0ac6c6_0
  - llvm-openmp==13.0.1=he0ac6c6_1
  - libzlib==1.2.11=h166bdaf_1014
  - libxml2==2.9.12=h72842e0_0
  - libxkbcommon==1.0.3=he3ba5ed_0
  - libxcb==1.13=h1bed415_1
  - libwebp-base==1.2.1=h7f98852_0
  - libvorbis==1.3.7=h7b6447c_0
  - libuuid==2.32.1=h7f98852_1000
  - libtiff==4.3.0=hf544144_1
  - libstdcxx-ng==13.2.0=h7e041cc_4
  - libstdcxx-devel_linux-64==9.5.0=h367e8d2_17
  - libssh2==1.10.0=h37d81fd_2
  - libsodium==1.0.18=h7b6447c_0
  - libsanitizer==9.5.0=hf86b28c_17
  - libprotobuf==3.15.8=h780b84a_1
  - libpq==13.3=hd57d9b9_3
  - libpng==1.6.37=hbc83047_0
  - libopus==1.3.1=h7b6447c_0
  - libopenblas==0.3.17=pthreads_h8fe5266_1
  - libogg==1.3.4=h27cfd23_1
  - libnghttp2==1.43.0=h812cca2_1
  - libllvm14==14.0.4=he0ac6c6_0
  - libllvm11==11.1.0=h9e868ea_6
  - libiconv==1.16=h7f8727e_2
  - libgomp==13.2.0=h807b86a_4
  - libglib==2.68.4=h174f98d_1
  - libgfortran5==11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - libgfortran-ng==11.2.0=h00389a5_1
  - libgcc-ng==13.2.0=h807b86a_4
  - libgcc-devel_linux-64==9.5.0=h367e8d2_17
  - libffi==3.4.2=h6a678d5_6
  - libevent==2.1.10=h9b69904_4
  - libev==4.33=h7f8727e_1
  - libedit==3.1.20191231=h14c3975_1
  - libdeflate==1.7=h27cfd23_5
  - libcxxabi==16.0.6=ha770c72_0
  - libcxx==16.0.6=h00ab1b0_0
  - libcurl==7.79.1=h2574ce0_1
  - libclang-cpp14==14.0.4=default_h2e3cab8_0
  - libclang==11.1.0=default_ha53f305_1
  - libbrotlienc==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - libbrotlidec==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - libbrotlicommon==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - lerc==2.2.1=h2531618_0
  - leidenalg==0.8.9=py39h5a03fae_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64==2.36.1=hea4e1c9_2
  - ld64_osx-64==609=hc8a64a7_10
  - lcms2==2.12=h3be6417_0
  - krb5==1.19.2=h3790be6_4
  - kiwisolver==1.3.2=py39h295c915_0
  - keyutils==1.6.1=h166bdaf_0
  - jupyter_core==4.8.1=py39h06a4308_0
  - jupyter==1.0.0=py39h06a4308_8
  - jpeg==9d=h7f8727e_0
  - jedi==0.18.0=py39h06a4308_1
  - jbig==2.1=hdba287a_0
  - isl==0.22.1=h295c915_3
  - ipython==7.28.0=py39hef51801_0
  - ipykernel==6.9.1=py39h06a4308_0
  - importlib-metadata==4.8.1=py39h06a4308_0
  - igraph==0.9.7=hf5496dd_0
  - icu==68.1=h2531618_0
  - hdf5==1.10.6=nompi_h6a2412b_1114
  - harfbuzz==3.0.0=h83ec7ef_1
  - h5py==3.1.0=nompi_py39h25020de_100
  - gxx_linux-64==9.5.0=h43f449f_10
  - gxx_impl_linux-64==9.5.0=h6c5bc03_17
  - gstreamer==1.18.5=h76c114f_0
  - gst-plugins-base==1.18.5=hf529b03_0
  - gsl==2.7.1=h6e86dc7_1
  - grpcio==1.37.1=py39hff7568b_0
  - grpc-cpp==1.37.1=hfc4d69e_3
  - graphite2==1.3.13=h23475e2_0
  - gmp==6.2.1=h295c915_3
  - glpk==4.65=h276157c_3
  - glib-tools==2.68.4=h9c3ff4c_1
  - glib==2.68.4=h9c3ff4c_1
  - giflib==5.2.1=h5eee18b_3
  - gfortran_osx-64==9.3.0=h478926d_15
  - gfortran_linux-64==9.5.0=hdb51d14_10
  - gfortran_impl_osx-64==9.3.0=h06163ed_23
  - gfortran_impl_linux-64==9.5.0=hf1096a2_19
  - gettext==0.19.8.1=h9b4dc7a_1
  - gcc_linux-64==9.5.0=h4258300_10
  - gcc_impl_linux-64==9.5.0=h6c5bc03_17
  - future==0.18.2=py39h06a4308_1
  - fribidi==1.0.10=h7b6447c_0
  - freetype==2.10.4=h5ab3b9f_0
  - fontconfig==2.13.1=hba837de_1005
  - fftw==3.3.10=nompi_hf0379b8_106
  - expat==2.4.1=h2531618_2
  - entrypoints==0.3=py39h06a4308_0
  - debugpy==1.4.1=py39h295c915_0
  - dbus==1.13.6=hb2f20db_0
  - cycler==0.10.0=py39h06a4308_0
  - curl==7.79.1=h2574ce0_1
  - cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0
  - compiler-rt==14.0.4=h924138e_0
  - clangxx_osx-64==14.0.4=he67212d_2
  - clangxx==14.0.4=default_ha074a59_0
  - clang_osx-64==14.0.4=hfcf283a_2
  - clang-14==14.0.4=default_h2e3cab8_0
  - clang==14.0.4=ha770c72_0
  - chardet==4.0.0=py39h06a4308_1003
  - cffi==1.14.6=py39h4bc2ebd_2
  - certifi==2023.11.17=py39h06a4308_0
  - cctools_osx-64==973.0.1=hd2fa2e2_10
  - cairo==1.16.0=h6cf1ce9_1008
  - ca-certificates==2023.12.12=h06a4308_0
  - c-ares==1.17.2=h7f98852_0
  - bzip2==1.0.8=h7b6447c_0
  - bwidget==1.9.14=ha770c72_1
  - brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003
  - brotli-bin==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - brotli==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - bottleneck==1.3.5=py39h7deecbd_0
  - blinker==1.4=py39h06a4308_0
  - binutils_linux-64==2.36=hf3e587d_10
  - binutils_impl_linux-64==2.36.1=h193b22a_2
  - beautifulsoup4==4.12.2=py39h06a4308_0
  - babel==2.11.0=py39h06a4308_0
  - async-timeout==3.0.1=py39h06a4308_0
  - astor==0.8.1=py39h06a4308_0
  - arpack==3.7.0=hdefa2d7_2
  - argon2-cffi==20.1.0=py39h27cfd23_1
  - anyio==3.5.0=py39h06a4308_0
  - anndata==0.7.8=py39hf3d152e_1
  - alsa-lib==1.2.3.2=h166bdaf_0
  - aiohttp==3.7.4.post0=py39h7f8727e_2
  - abseil-cpp==20210324.2=h2531618_0
  - _openmp_mutex==4.5=2_kmp_llvm
  - _libgcc_mutex==0.1=conda_forge

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: There is every chance the original environment file was meant for another platform (e.g., x86_64 Linux), or for a different Python version. And then these specific package versions may not be available for your platform / Python combination.

Comment: Notice how a lot of the package specifiers have py39 in their name, so probably this environment file was made with (and for) Python 3.9. You don't list the file itself; it may be specified in there (in fact, it should be).

Comment: Please read and follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular there are emphasized sections #2, 'Search, and research', and #3, 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem'. It looks like other questions and answers address some of this like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48493505/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65072530/8508004). What about yours isn't covered there?

Comment: Channels are out of order (`conda-forge` should be at top, followed by `bioconda`) and this looks like a **linux-64** environment, not **osx-64**. You may also have to switch the `channel_priority` configuration option to `flexible` in order to solve the environment.

Comment: the first two were correct in that the environment was meant for Linux, not the platform I'm using. Thanks for your help. 

To "Wayne", I actually found those exact posts and those didnt help, as stated in my post. Your comment was unnecessary but I appreciate it.