# Using a pip requirements file in a conda yml file throws AttributeError: 'FileNotFoundError'

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have a `requirements.txt` like

```
numpy
```

and an `environment.yml` containing

```yaml
# run via: conda env create --file environment.yml
---
name: test
dependencies:
  - python>=3
  - pip
  - pip:
      - -r file:requirements.txt
```

when I then run `conda env create --file environment.yml` I get

> Pip subprocess output:
>
> Pip subprocess error:
> ERROR: Exception:

<... error traceback in pip >

> AttributeError: 'FileNotFoundError' object has no attribute 'read'
>
> failed
>
> CondaEnvException: Pip failed

It is also strange how pip is called, as reported just before the error occurs:

```
['$HOME/.conda/envs/test/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '$HOME/test/condaenv.8d3003nm.requirements.txt']
```

(I replace my home path with `$HOME`)
Note the weird expansion of the `requirements.txt`.

Any ideas?

Comment: That command at the end is normal: Conda takes the whole `pip:` section and translates it to a temporary `requirements.txt` and the explicit `-r file:requirements.txt` will be nested inside that file (see [this code](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/33a142c16530fcdada6c377486f1c1a385738a96/conda_env/installers/pip.py#L19)). Is the directory (`$HOME/test`) writable? I.e., perhaps Conda is having trouble generating the temporary file? If you just do `- numpy` under the `pip:` section does it work?

Comment: @merv Yes, `$HOME/test` is writable. Yes, replacing `-r file:requirements.txt` with `- numpy` works just fine.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Changes to Pip Behavior in 21.2.1

[A recent change in the Pip code](https://github.com/SymbiFlow/symbiflow-examples/issues/169#issuecomment-889706758) has changed its behavior to be more strict with respect to `file:` URI syntax. [As pointed out](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10237#issuecomment-889676833) by a PyPA member and Pip developer, the syntax `file:requirements.txt` is not a valid URI according to [the RFC8089 specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8089).

Instead, one must either drop the `file:` scheme altogether:

```yaml
name: test
dependencies:
  - python>=3
  - pip
  - pip:
    - -r requirements.txt
```

or provide a valid URI, which means using an absolute path (or a local file server):

```yaml
name: test
dependencies:
  - python>=3
  - pip
  - pip:
    - -r file:/full/path/to/requirements.txt
    # - -r file:///full/path/to/requirements.txt # alternate syntax
```