# Conda ModuleNotFoundError in a virtual environment

Tags: python, miniconda

There are obviously similar questions a lot, but I have to ask this same thing again since I can not find a solution (which works) from the other questions (nor anywhere else with reasonable search).

Also note that I have just started with Python. 
Also I feel it's needed to explain all that I currently have. So ... sorry for the long post

**The Main problem**

I have a legacy Python project that I would need to get to work locally (on Ubuntu 20.04). This project has environment.yml and requirements.txt files.

A virtual environment is created with:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

This creates the virtual environment, which I can activate and see it has 'flask' installed.

```
conda list |grep flask
>> flask                     1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi

pip list |grep Flask
>> flask                     1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
```

But when I attempt to run the application, I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

The versions for the 'flask' were actually 1.1.2 for conda and 1.1.1 for pip at the beginning, but I changed these to be the same at some point (same error nevertheless, tried several other versions as well).

**Main question**: What am I doing/having wrong?

**What I have and what I have tried**

I tried doing the pip install by the *requirements.txt* after the environment was created. I did this both in- and outside of the virtual environment.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But this results in a lot of errors because of libraries not found, so I think it is perhaps out of date (or just doesn't work with my current environments). I understand it is supposed to represent the libraries installed for the environment where the application works. (My guess is that this is originally taken from the container running the app?)

I did find a solution that worked. I manually installed the flask (and several other libraries after that) with apt:

```
sudo apt install python3-flask
```

However this is obviously not the right solution as the libraries are supposed to be only in the virtual environment (afaik). Also it seems this worked once with pip (maybe with anaconda ... don't know anymore. Couldn't make it happen again.).
I think I could maybe write these requirements by hand to a new "requirments_local.txt" and use that if I could the pip install work again but I think this would be wrong (why to have environment.yml and a requirements -file?). (the environment.yml has also *pip* libraries to install)

I don't think this is significant, but writing this down just in case.
The application is started via two bash-scripts where the 1st one sets up some runtime settings and then calls another script (entrypoint.sh which is used by the container also) which ultimately has this line to start the actual application:

```
exec gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 myapp:app
```

(Seems to be ok, since the app starts in a docker container and even locally when ?globally? installing the dependencies)
The virtual environment is activated before calling the 2nd script, by having this line in the script:

```
source activate $env_name
```

I am using *source* since I noticed 'conda activate $env_name' did not work. I checked that the correct environment is in use by executing 'conda env list > conda.txt' in different stages at both scripts.

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and have these installed:

- Python 2.7.18 (Python)
- Python 3.8.10 (Python3)
- pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

  - pip3 gives the same
- conda 4.10.3 (by installing miniconda)

I have also tried using *anaconda* instead of *miniconda* since there seems to be some dependencies in *requirements.txt* pointing to anaconda, but the error with the flask was the same.

**Additional questions**: Can I omit the *requirements.txt* from the version control or can it be integrated somehow with the *environment.yml*? It does not feel right to have library versions listed in two files. What is even the purpose of the requirements when already creating the virtual environment?

Comment: Also when starting the app (without scripts in the middle) having the virtual environment activated, the result is just the same.

Comment: This also happened to me, I solved using the whole path to activate the env: `source /home/user/anaconda3/bin/activate`. The problem is that Python path is not taking the library from the correct env.

Comment: RE: integration, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59056234/570918

Comment: As for a concrete answer, share the `environment.yml` and `requirements.txt`. If they are long, consider adding them as GitHub Gists and linking.

Comment: @razimbres I gave this a try, but it did not work. Though it gave me an idea. The GreenUnicorn was actually installed with apt, so maybe it directs it to use wrong libraries also and not the ones in the virtual environment. Have to look for a way to install and use it through conda/pip.

Comment: I found this few days later and could be the issue in the case of @Razimbres: You need to have a PATH environment variable set for your Python installation. If you haven't configured this variable, you need to give the full directory path to where your Python executable is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although suggestion by @razimbres was not actually correct, it gave me an idea to think for reasons why the libraries are not found from the virtual environment. (Could there be something that directs the app to look for libraries outside the env)

I had installed the green unicorn by *apt* since the absence of it was the first error when originally starting the app.

```
exec gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 myapp:app
```

> ./entrypoint.sh: line 62: exec: gunicorn: not found

Since it was missing from the *environment.yml* and not knowing any better, I installed it via *apt* (since it was there ... though someone could now explain why? It clearly just messes up things.).

I added to the *environment.yml* the following (conda) dependency:
- gunicorn==20.1.0

Then created the environment again:

```
conda env remove --name $env_name
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

And now it works. (even starting with the scripts)
I think the lesson was: *Do not use apt for installing any python resources.*

Also. If you had any, uninstall all python resources installed via apt. Like in my case:

```
sudo apt remove gunicorn
```

Ps. Also it seems that the *requirements.txt* is not needed. Maybe it can be removed (later). Feels it is just causing confusion at the moment.

Comment: Adding few more pointers here.

1. Run `which gunicorn` to properly understand , which gunicorn is getting picked up.
It will help to identify , whether its pointing to a global gunicorn.

2. After unistalling using `sudo apt remove gunicorn` and installing it in virtal env using pip , you may get error saying `bash: /usr/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory`.
Kill your terminal session and open it again to fix this issue.
This forces the shell to refresh its memory of executable paths.