# Installing Spacy language models directly from Conda environment.yml

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, spacy

In hopes of facilitating the installation of a tool I have built, I would like to have an `enviroment.yml` file that could help install all the required dependencies. I do have one, however, Spacy language models require an additional download via (for example) `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`.

My issue is that I would like to have this model downloaded from a simple `conda env create -f environment.yml`. I know that pip packages can be installed via Conda, but do not know how to perform the "download" inside the `environment.yml` file. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you wish to have your environment.yml file contain pip imports as well? Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245401/combining-conda-environment-yml-with-pip-requirements-txt. Other helpful info might be how to install pip in a conda environment, ``conda install -n myenv pip`` (more info here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment).

Comment: Are you saying that adding a few lines like "- spacy: en_core_web_sm" will behave the same as "python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm"?

Comment: The issue is different from the one you sent. Following that issue, these couple of lines should do the trick: "- spacy: en_core_web_sm", but they do not install the model. It might be because download and install are different.

Comment: @Elmstead no need for Pip - Conda Forge packages the models directly (see https://github.com/conda-forge/spacy-models-feedstock).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the Spacy documentation](https://spacy.io/api/cli#download) of `download` command states:

> **DOWNLOADING BEST PRACTICES**
> The `download` command is mostly intended as a convenient, interactive wrapper – it performs compatibility checks and prints detailed messages in case things go wrong. It’s **not recommended** to use this command as part of an automated process. If you know which package your project needs, you should consider [a direct download via pip](https://spacy.io/usage/models#download-pip), or uploading the package to a local PyPI installation and fetching it straight from there. This will also allow you to add it as a versioned package dependency to your project.

While it is possible to include PyPI dependencies in a Conda environment YAML, Conda Forge also publishes Spacy models as packages via [the `spacy-models-feedstock`](https://github.com/conda-forge/spacy-models-feedstock). In the example from OP, this would mean adding the package `spacy-model-en_core_web_sm`.