# Conda Create Environment from requirements.txt

Tags: python, package, conda, environment, requirements.txt

Hej!

I downloaded a github project and need the EXACT requirements to run this project (Pytorch/CNN).

There is a requirements.txt file and would therefore like to install all packages in a new environment.

First, I tried to use `pip install requirements.txt` in a new created environment, but it got really bugged and there were some conflicts so I had to install some packages manually, which leaded to more conflicts (One package seems do need another python version as another one)

Afterwards I mixed coda/pip, which lead to some dependency issues...

So currently I try to use `conda create --name wnetnn --file ./requirements.txt`.

But it returns the following:

```
CondaValueError: could not parse ' p y d e n s e c r f   @   g i t + h t t p s : / / g i t h u b . c o m / l u c a s b - e y e r / p y d e n s e c r f . g i t @ 0 d 5 3 a c b c f 5 1 2 3 d 4 c 8 8 0 4 0 f e 6 8 f b b 9 8 0 5 f c 5 b 2 f b 9 ' in: ./requirements.txt
```

Is there any solution for it? Or any other approach? If not, may it be also an solution to create an empty conda environment and try to install all packages with conda from txt file manually.

Thank you SO much! :)

-> Windows 10Pro 64bit, Anaconda Navigator 2.2.0 -> And all python version used in environments from 3.4 to 3.9

Comment: With `pip`, the command is `pip install -r requirements.txt`. If all the dependencies are pinned to a specific version (as they should in a `.txt` requirement file; then it will work. If not, then you are going to have to deal with the conflicts yourself.

Comment: Have you tried manually converting your `requirements.txt` to a `environment.yml` so that you *can* use `--file environment.yml`? this is probably what you should do

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59056234/570918) in the duplicate shows how to use a `requirements.txt` with a Conda environment. Note that you wouldn't need the `anaconda` dependency.